# Конвертер из CSV в XMLS / CSV to XLSX converter

Tags: cmd, bat, for

Имеется exe-файл, который конвертирует CSV в XLSX. Необходимо передавать в него параметры обходя каждый CSV в папке.

```
"%cd%\Convert\csv2xlsx_amd64.exe" -colsep "," -sheet "9bdb933f-30d4-46ae-ac22-16c3473"  -outfile "%cd%\Download_File\File.xlsx" -infile "%cd%\Download_File\*.csv"
```

Код выше работает из cmd, но только для одного файла и приходится задавать параметры вручную.
Не могу понять как в цикле обработать и чтобы задать параметры:

- sheet - у каждого документа разное название листа;
- outfile - чтобы был похож названием на CSV.

Помогите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Банальная ошибка для новичка - плохо читать мануал.

Для решения потребовалось:

1. Использовать `!name!` вместо `%name%` - чтобы обойти все файлы.

Сам код:

```
for %%i in ("%cd%\Download_File\*.csv") do (
set name=%%~ni
"%cd%\Convert\csv2xlsx_amd64.exe" -colsep "," -sheet "test"  -outfile "%cd%\Download_File\!name!.xlsx" -infile "%cd%\Download_File\!name!.csv"
)
```

В названии листа можно использовать любое значение
`-sheet "test"`

Примечание:

Я пытался автоматизировать конвертер из CSV в XLSX, но не находил ответа в просторах интернета. Наткнулся на данную разработку в gitlab ([Конвертер CSV в XLSX](https://gitlab.com/DerLinkshaender/csv2xlsx/-/blob/master/csv2xlsx_amd64.exe)), спасибо большое им. Решил поделиться со всеми, кто также не мог найти подход к конвертеру.